# Grails template inline javascript vs external file javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have a template in a Grails project in which I have a click function on a button that appears in the template. I have noticed that if I include this click function code (jQuery) inline with the template's markup code inside 'script' tags of course, it works but as soon as I move the click function code to an outside file and try to include that file in the template by

```
<g:javascript src="externalFile.js" />
```

then the click function doesn't work. I would like to know why this is. What makes it more mysterious is that some of the javascript in the external file does work.

Here is the code of the click function (actually this is the entire external file I am trying to use):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });

    $("#search").click( function() {
        $('#AdminConsole p').css("font-size", "30px");
        $("#AdminConsole p").html("Individuals Search Screen Results " + "<br />" + "Batch ID " + selectedBatchID + ": " + selectedBatchDesc);
    });

});
```

The #search button is on the template and the '#AdminConsole p' is a text label on the main gsp that is already there before the template is even loaded later on the page.

Comment: Can you show the click function that isn't working?

Comment: @Jeff Beck Edited question to comply.

Answer (score 1):

When the code is moved to an external file you need to put in inside a [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure that it doesn't execute before the DOM is ready

```
$(function() {
    $("#search").click( function() {
        $('#AdminConsole p').css("font-size", "30px");
        $("#AdminConsole p").html("Individuals Search Screen Results " + "<br />" + "Batch ID " + selectedBatchID + ": " + selectedBatchDesc);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried just that. See my edited question above. I couldn't paste that code in this comment because it would have looked too ugly. I also tried to put it outside DOM ready.

Comment: The funny thing is that the 'tabs' function does seem to work but not the 'search' one when I try the external file method.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments the *tabs* function does work from the external file, so the file is working. I would view the source of the rendered page to make sure that there is exactly one element with the id of *search* on the final page sent back to the browser.

Also I would suggest adding the following the to click function for debugging.

```
console.log("Click Fired")
```

You should be able to narrow down if its that the click isn't being called correctly or if the work you are doing in the function isn't happening correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this console logging for debugging.